# php-xdebug can only be installed for php 8

Tags: package-management, software-installation, php, xdebug

I am having on my system:

```
$ php --version
PHP 7.4.2 (cli) (built: Feb  1 2020 17:49:29) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.2, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

When trying to install `php-xdebug`, I only get it for php8:

```
$ sudo apt-get install php-xdebug
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  php8.0-common php8.0-xdebug
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  php-xdebug php8.0-common php8.0-xdebug
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 200 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1.507 kB of archives.
After this operation, 10,8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

However, I need it for my already installed php 7.4 version. As you can see `xdebug` is not installed for used `php --version`.

Any suggestions how to specifically install it for php 7.4

I really appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 3):

I've been looking for a solution to this and found Ondřej Surý's PPA, which you can install with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.4-xdebug
```

Here it worked for me,

Hope this helps.